# RAP 2.0 Hello World example Entry Point not found

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rap

I installed the complete IDE package and the RAP target. After that I wanted to try the "Hello world" example, as you can found here [example](http://eclipse.org/rap/developers-guide/devguide.php?topic=hello-world.html&version=2.0), but I dont' have the class BasicEntryPoint, which is described in "Create the application UI". After "Launch the application" which is also explained in the example, I get the error:

```
2013-04-23 20:07:26.970:INFO:oejs.Server:jetty-8.1.9.v20130131
osgi> 2013-04-23 20:07:27.033:INFO:oejs.AbstractConnector:Started     
SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:49944
2013-04-23 20:07:30.219:WARN:oejs.ServletHandler:ERROR:  /rap
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Entry point not found: /rap
at org.eclipse.rap.rwt.internal.lifecycle.EntryPointManager.getEntryPointRegistration(EntryPointManager.java:68)
at org.eclipse.rap.rwt.internal.service.StartupPage.getCurrentEntryPointProperties(StartupPage.java:151)
at org.eclipse.rap.rwt.internal.service.StartupPage.writeEntryPointProperty(StartupPage.java:160)
at org.eclipse.rap.rwt.internal.service.StartupPage.writeTitle(StartupPage.java:81)
at org.eclipse.rap.rwt.internal.service.StartupPage$StartupPageValueProvider.writeVariable(StartupPage.java:173)
at org.eclipse.rap.rwt.internal.service.StartupPageTemplate.writePage(StartupPageTemplate.java:52)
at org.eclipse.rap.rwt.internal.service.StartupPage.send(StartupPage.java:65)
at org.eclipse.rap.rwt.internal.service.LifeCycleServiceHandler.handleGetRequest(LifeCycleServiceHandler.java:87)
at org.eclipse.rap.rwt.internal.service.LifeCycleServiceHandler.synchronizedService(LifeCycleServiceHandler.java:77)
at org.eclipse.rap.rwt.internal.service.LifeCycleServiceHandler.service(LifeCycleServiceHandler.java:61)
at org.eclipse.rap.rwt.engine.RWTServlet.handleValidRequest(RWTServlet.java:107)
at org.eclipse.rap.rwt.engine.RWTServlet.handleRequest(RWTServlet.java:94)
at org.eclipse.rap.rwt.engine.RWTServlet.doGet(RWTServlet.java:80)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:735)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
at org.eclipse.rap.rwt.osgi.internal.CutOffContextPathWrapper.service(CutOffContextPathWrapper.java:106)
at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.service(ServletRegistration.java:61)
at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(ProxyServlet.java:128)
at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyServlet.java:60)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
at org.eclipse.equinox.http.jetty.internal.HttpServerManager$InternalHttpServiceServlet.service(HttpServerManager.java:386)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:669)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:457)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:229)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1075)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:384)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:193)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1009)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:368)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:488)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:932)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:994)
at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:640)
at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:235)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:82)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:628)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:52)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

What's wrong? I feel like the example description is wrong...

Answer (score 1):

I'm also new to RAP and run into the same issue. And I agree with you, that this "Hello World" example is incomplete. The solution you can find here (you have to create this class manually (BasicEntryPoint)):

[RAP Entry Point](http://eclipse.org/rap/developers-guide/devguide.php?topic=hello-world.html&version=2.0#entrypoint)

Additionally you have to add the entry point to you configuration (plugin.xml):

```
   <extension
     point="org.eclipse.rap.ui.entrypoint">
  <entrypoint
        class="org.examples.rap.helloworld.BasicEntryPoint"
        id="entrypoint1"
        path="/rap">
  </entrypoint>
```